# isJavaType(Class class) or isUserType(Class class)?

Tags: java, reflection

Is there a way to find out if the type is native from java enviroment?

Comment: What is the difference between JavaType and UserType? A type, developed and packed by Sun/Oracle? If you can give a precise distinction, it should be possible to do so prorgramatically.

Comment: Yes. I mean java classes shipped with JVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with 100% certainty, no. You could test whether the package name starts with "java", but that's easy to spoof in most environments. In some JVMs, you can test whether the classloader for the class is null; it will be null for system classes.

Comment: +1 - The test for a `null` classloader is actually testing if the classloader if the "bootstrap classloader".  You can run a JVM with extra JARs on the bootstrap classpath ... but that effectively makes the classes in those JAR files system classes.

Comment: java, javax, org.omg, org.xml, org.w3c and org.ietf according to my Javadocs. For a quick'n'dirty solution it might be ok, but it's not secure for the future or cheatresistant. :)

Comment: Thank you very much. This code works nicely for my app: public boolean isUserType(Class<?> clazz) { return clazz.getClassLoader() == null ? false : true; }

Comment: @CelinHC: I can't resist suggesting that you just write the following instead: public boolean isUserType(Class<?> clazz) { return clazz.getClassLoader() != null; }

Comment: @Ernest: As you wish. Thank you!

Comment: Another suggestion: static. Since no internal attribute (state) is read or written, it can be made static.